# Is there a "requests for reopen" queue here on meta?

Tags: discussion, reopen-closed, meta

Is there a "requests for reopen" queue here on meta? I can't find it view a Google search restricted to stats.meta.stackexchange.com nor via a search within meta.

Answer (score 10):

Yes: https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/review/reopen. It can be reached through the 'Review Queues' icon on the top bar (which looks like a horizontal bar chart with a tick in the bottom-right corner).

Comment: (Note: "tick" is British for *check mark*.)

Comment: You seem to have misunderstood my question. I meant a thread on meta in which people post requests to reopen positings on main, and where they discuss pros and cons of reopening.

Comment: @MichaelHardy: Sorry - no there isn't one of those. Discussion of the pros & cons of re-opening usually takes place on the post in question, as comments. Sometimes people post on Meta about a particular question.